# I am facing some strange behaviour with a try/catch block

Tags: solidity, erc-20, bsc, openzeppelin-contracts

I have the following `_transfer` method implementation in my ERC20 token.

```
  function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal override {
        require(transfersEnabled || essentialAddress[from] || essentialAddress[to], "Transfers not allowed");

        if (amount == 0) {
            super._transfer(from, to, 0);
            return;
        }

        uint256 currentBalanceFrom = balanceOf(from);
        uint256 currentBalanceTo = balanceOf(to);
        
        //  Deduct the fee if necessary
        uint256 fees = calculateFee(amount, from, to);
        if (fees > 0) {
            super._transfer(from, address(this), fees);
        }
        super._transfer(from, to, amount - fees);
        handleBalanceUpdate(from, to, currentBalanceFrom, currentBalanceTo); <-- Something strange is happening here
        _distributeFee();
    }
```

The method calls `handleBalanceUpdate`:

When calling

```
function handleBalanceUpdate( address from, address to, uint256 oldBalanceFrom, uint256 oldBlanceTo) internal {
        if (address(rewardsManager) != address(0)) {
            try rewardsManager.notifyBalanceUpdate(from, oldBalanceFrom) {} catch { console.log("Fail"); }
            try rewardsManager.notifyBalanceUpdate(to, oldBlanceTo) {} catch { console.log("Fail"); }
        }
    }
```

Problem is that when `rewardsManager.notifyBalanceUpdate` reverts, the whole transfer gets reverted silently, no exception is thrown. I am expecting the transfer to happen normally regardless if `rewardsManager.notifyBalanceUpdate` fails or not.

Did you guys face anything similar?

Comment: Are you sure it reverts du to try/catch? I tried with similar code and it worked as expected.

Comment: Yes, but only when running on a local testnet. Tried reproducing it in my unit tests and it works. This is giving me anxiety.

Comment: Can you `import "hardhat/console.sol";` and print something on each line and the run it when its suppossed to revert and check if any of the prints got hit? that way we could ensure its actually reverting, or if is not

Comment: I triedi and It's not reverting, Issue only happens when ` rewardsManager.notifyBalanceUpdate` makes an internal call to a destroyed contract

Comment: @pxr_64 Do you have a failed transaction hash? Can you include an complete reproducible example? I tried with an small example and it works as expected. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: The thing is that the transaction does not fail, only that the balances do not get updated if `rewardsManager.notifyBalanceUpdate` fails internally. Did some more digging, and the error only happens when running in my local environment. I've set up a ganache environment by forking the BSC chain. I tried reproducing the issue on the BSC test net and it behaves normally, also tested in remix browser network, and it works as expected.

Comment: Perhaps it is a bug in the ganache version, you may try downgrading/upgrading or checkout the code into a different directory. The code seems to be working according to your tests in BSC testnet.